# Swift: How to pass data between unique UITableViewCells in the same UITableViewController

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController that has two unique custom UITableViewCells. The unique cells are a `HeaderCell` (row 0) that contains the price of an entire order in a UILabel called `orderPriceLabel`, and `ItemCell` (rows 1+) which has an `itemPriceLabel` which stores the price of each item at its index path as well as a `countLabel` which stores the number of times each item has been added to the order.

Each `ItemCell` has a `+` UIButton and a `-` UIButton. Each time the `+` button is tapped, the `countLabel` at the corresponding index path increases, and if the `-` button is tapped, the `countLabel` decreases. This part works how I'd like it to. What I'm struggling with is updating the `orderPriceLabel` in the `HeaderCell` at row 0. When the `+` button is tapped, the `orderPriceLabel` should increase by the value stored in the `ItemCell`'s `itemPriceLabel`, and the opposite should happen when the `-` button is tapped.

ItemCell code:

```
class ItemCell: UITableViewCell {

// MARK: Properties
@IBOutlet weak var itemOrderCountLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var itemPriceLabel: UILabel!

var count: Int = 0

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)


}

@IBAction func decrementButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    count -= 1
    itemOrderCountLabel.text = "\(count)"
    //How to decrease orderPriceLabel

}

@IBAction func incrementButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    count += 1
    itemOrderCountLabel.text = "\(count)"
    //How to increase orderPriceLabel

}
```

HeaderCell code:

```
class FoodMenuTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

// MARK: Properties
@IBOutlet weak var orderPriceLabel: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)


}
```

TableViewController Code:

```
class FoodMenuTableVC: UITableViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    itemList.count + 1

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.row == 0 {

        let cellIdentifier = "headerCell"

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! HeaderCell

        //cell.orderPriceLabel.text = ....?

        return cell

    } else {

        //This works fine

        let cellIdentifier = "itemCell"

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ItemCell

        let name = localSelectedVendorName!


            let keys = Array(itemList.keys)
            let values = Array(itemList.values)

            cell.itemPriceLabel.text = String(values[indexPath.row - 1].price)
            cell.itemOrderCountLabel.text = " "

        }

        return cell
    }
```

I'm quite a noob to swift and programming in general.

Thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend storing your total price in a class variable (property). Add this line of code above `viewDidLoad` in your TableViewController class:

```
var totalPrice = 0
```

This creates a variable that can be easily accessed throughout the entire class. When you click the + or – button in your `ItemCell`, add the necessary value to `totalPrice` like this, where `itemPriceValue` is what you're adding:

```
self.totalPrice += itemPriceValue
```

Now, you can make your `orderPriceLabel` equal to the value of `totalPrice`. Also, to make sure that the UITableView updates, add this method to the bottom of your TableViewController code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: I don't think this works because the button is stored in the ItemCell class. Currently I'm using a global variable that updates properly, but it isn't updated in the HeaderCell.